# Reduce launcher icon size on vertical panel

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5

Kubuntu 16.04 amd64. Plasma 5.5
My desktop here:
[image]

How to reduce launcher icon "K" size?

Comment: I think the size of the "K" icon is proportional to the width of your panel.

Comment: KDE tracker bug: Bug 378443 - Plasma 5 start-button gets too big when the panel is vertical - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378443. Fixed with the plasma 5.10 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @user26687:

> KDE tracker bug: Bug 378443 - Plasma 5 start-button gets too big when
>   the panel is vertical - [bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378443](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378443). Fixed
>   with the plasma 5.10 or later.

I'm update files:

https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/commit/?id=200d5a73cbdb76a1b0df29c5cf502fd88b922542

https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/commit/?id=e3869e559da25d2fecdfb5418a5af6079a1dc2b3

https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/commit/?id=b45cb75675c92924db4b38ebc55d9ab93d53fb1f

and my issue fixed on my 5.8.7 version (I'm update plasma):

[image]